# Open, Closed, Bound and Unbound Generic types

Tags: generics

I've read a number of posts about this but I'm still not sure that I fully understand the definitions.

Here's what I think are examples of the different terms.  Am I on the right track here, or do I still not understand the concepts.  Thanks

```
Array<T TArray> - unbound and open.
Array<int> - bound and closed.
Array<Array<T TArray> - bound and open.
Array<Array<int>> - bound and closed.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unbound means something like `typeof(Dictionary<,>)`. Unbound types are only interesting for Reflection and can only be used in `typeof()`, not in any other context.
All unbounds types are closed types, the combination "unbound and open" is impossible.

Assuming T is a type parameter of the current class/method:

```
Dictionary<,> - unbound and closed
Dictionary<string, int> - constructed and closed
Dictionary<int, T> - constructed and open
Dictionary<string, List<T>> - constructed and open
NonGenericClass - bound and closed
```

Note that there is no such thing as `List<Dictionary<,>>` - unbound types cannot be used as type arguments, only directly in `typeof()`. A type is either unbound, or completely bound.
And if a type is unbound, there's no place where it could refer to a type parameter, so the combination "unbound and open" is impossible.